# Excel - Call a function within a function

Tags: excel-formula

Scenerio - I have an Excel formula that counts the number of "YES" entries in a column then divides that count by another count of "YES" entries in a different column

```
=COUNTIF('All Project Tasks'!AC203:AC236,"YES")/COUNTIF('All Project Tasks'!AB203:AB236,"YES")
```

This works.

However, I now need to add a criteria that checks to see if the date in a date column is <= to today and if so, it should result with "Not Started" instead of the division result.

So far I have this:

```
=IF(D12<=TODAY(),COUNTIF('All Project Tasks'!AC2:AC18,"YES")/COUNTIF('All Project Tasks'!AB2:AB18,"YES"),"Not Started")
```

The "Not Started" part works in this formula but the division part is failing. I receive 0 instead of the decimal number that I get by using the first formula above.

I'm thinking I'm just missing one piece but cannot find what it is.

Comment: Did the formatting of your cell change to integers?  Select the cell, Format->Format Cells->Number

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the results from the formulas in different cells, then diving the cells by eachother